# Font rendering libraries for C# / dot-NET?

Tags: c#, .net, text, fonts, gdi+

Are there any free, third-party libraries for rendering arbitrarily scaled and rotated text in dot-NET applications? Although native GDI+ allows for text scaling and rotation, its methods for determining the rendered text's dimensions are not sufficiently precise and the differences in kerning as text is added to a rendered string make it unsuitable for use in certain kinds of software (such as, for instance, graphics editing software).

Requirements:

- Native .NET code.
- Arbitrary scaling and rotation of text.
- Precise text metrics.
- Consistent kerning regardless of string length.

Comment: Do you visit this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628247/c-sharp-lib-for-processing-font-files-ttf-truetype-others

Answer (score 2):

Windows Presentation Foundation provides sophisticated support for [typography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typography-in-wpf).

Comment: Unfortunately, WPF is Vista-only.

Comment: actually, it is also available on XP SP2 if the .NET Framework 3.0 is installed

Comment: WPF is available on all platforms where .NET 3.0 installed

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know, and should be useful to other readers. I'm still looking for alternatives, though. I'm using XNA Game Studio 2.0 together with WinForms and don't yet want to move to .NET 3.0.