# C# lib for processing font files - TTF (TrueType), others

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, truetype

Any known C# library or project out there that can understand the TTF file format? Most questions Ive seen regarding this are attempting to do custom rendering, but I'm more interested in a font editor type of application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't know what you want to do exactly, but WPF has a cool [GlyphTypeface Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) that is quite abstract and quite independent.

This is how you can start with:

```
GlyphTypeface ttf = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"c:\windows\fonts\verdana.ttf"));
```

There are also the [GlyphRun Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrun.aspx) and the [GlyphRunDrawing Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrundrawing.aspx).

Otherwise, if you're looking for the big picture, open-source, you can also check the [FreeType Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType), available here: http://freetype.org/

Comment: Simon, are these low level enough to try to tackle a font editor application? Good info in any case

Comment: For a font editor, I would rather go for the FreeType Project. The WPF classes targets mostly font file parsing & glyph rendering, rather than glyph edition. Tough work ahead anyway :-)

Comment: so, now to find freetype ported to .net ;)

Answer (score 18):

I want to introduce another pure C# lib for processing font.
Here https://github.com/LayoutFarm/Typography

**Pure C#**

support .NET >=20

access general glyph data,

and access advanced typography data.

(such as GDEF,GSUB,GPOS) etc.

---

The below image shows some screen snapshot,

compare then lib's rendering glyph 'B'

1. (left) : glyph from the lib without Hinting
2. (middle) : Windows's GDI with clear type (from notepad)
3. (right):  glyph from the lib with True Hinting

[image]

---

snap 2:
I'm developing auto-hint, and grid fitting.

test it out, and feel free to comment, fork, discuss.

[image: triangulate1]

---

snap 3: subpixel rendering

[image: subpixel_rendering]

Comment: Pure C#. hooray!! C# world need a raw C# font/text library. I won't find the amazing project if you hadn't post here. Thank you!

Comment: Off the top of my head, could this be used to convert ttf fonts to woff?

Comment: This looks interesting. Doesn't seem to be any documentation for this though. Going to see if I can make sense of the demo examples.

Answer (score 8):

There is a .net wrapper for FreeType available here: https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont

It's also available on nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package SharpFont
```

Comment: https://github.com/ryancheung/FreeTypeSharp could be an option.